# Help reading chromatogram

Tags: human-biology, genetics, dna, homework, dna-sequencing

A genetic variation is found in this chromatogram:

[image]

It says that the "reference sequence" is the top line and that I can use the general genetic code to find the reading frame.

I can see that there are two N's instead of a G and a C. However I don't know what this means. I'm also not sure how I'd find the reading frame? I suppose I could look for a start and stop codon but I could read them both ways?

Last question: Is this change likely pathogenic? I'm not sure how to classify a variation as pathogenic or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the two Ns that you see are not necessarily variants, but rather likely just poor quality reads. Essentially when you sequence DNA and the sequencer can't make a call as to what the base is, it will just designate it N meaning that the base could be any of the four DNA bases.

As for finding the reading from, if you know this sequence contains a stop codon, that helps, and just look for any of the stop sequences. If not, look for bases that match codon sequences and if you get a full strand of sequence that codes for amino acids you will likely be correct.

For reference [here](http://jacksonstrickland.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/5/8/13584186/4324322.jpg?437) is a link to a codon chart that will help you decipher the reading frame.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes absolutely, could you tell me if you can, whether the mutation is likely to be pathogenic, though? And if so, why?

Comment: So as cagliari says above it does not look like you have any mutations. You cannot call N a mutation because this could be any base including the one from the reference genome.

Answer (score 2):

The traces you have come from [Sanger sequencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanger_sequencing). N in genetics means nucleotide (surprising right?). N is used when the base at a given location is unknown (or could be any base pairs).

In your case you have Ns because the base-calling software is unable to determine the nucleotide. The first N is due to two peaks overlapping (G and A signals) and the second one should be a C rather than a N.

From what I can see, you have no apparent mutations so no those changes are unlikely to be pathogenic. A mutation can be called when you know a base in the reference is modified in your sample, which is not the case here (simply N -> G and a N -> C). The signals for your Ns look very similar between your reference and your sample therefore not suggesting a mutation.

For the reading frame, you have to look for a start (ATG) and a stop codon (TAG,TAA or TGA) to identify the [open reading frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_reading_frame) (ORF). Multiple software do that and here a link to an online NCBI tool called [ORF Finder](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gorf/gorf.html).

As you pointed out the ORF can also be in the reverse strand. You don't want to look at the reverse sequence but at the **reverse complementary** sequence. Usually tools to detect ORFs have the option to look at both strands.